# teamcity octopus deploy handling multiple code branches (default and develop) with same project name

Tags: mercurial, nuget, teamcity-7.0, octopus-deploy

At the moment teamcity is watching and building a mercurial develop branch using the AssemblyInfoPatcher plugin and Project.Website.2.x.x.x.nupkg turns up in artifacts and octopus is deploying this to a staging environment. awesome stuff.

Now I am just trying to get my head around how to set up octopus deploy to handle the default branch getting deployed to production as well now.

I have set up teamcity to produce the Project.Website.1.x.x.x.nupkg from the default branch but how does octopus know which package is a staging build from the develop branch and which is production from the default branch seeing apart from version number they have the same project name as in Project.Website ?

At the moment I have a staging environment, staging roles and a staging project group. do I just need to create a new group environment and roles for production and if so how does octopus know how to do its bit?

Both tools awesome bits of kit and I am sure I'm pretty close now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to setup an environment for Production in Octopus Deploy.

Assumptions:

- Your Production environment in Octopus is named Production
- You are using octo.exe in a Command Line build step in TeamCity to create and deploy the releases.

You can use the `--deployto` option of octo.exe to specify an environment to deploy your newly created release to. Something like this:

`octo create-release --server=http://your-octopus/api --project=Project.Website --version=%build.number% --packageVersion=%build.number% --deployto=Production`

This command will:

- Create a release using your TeamCity build number as the version
- Use your TeamCity build number as the package version for all packages
- Deploy the release to the Production environment

TIP: Sometimes it takes a few seconds for TeamCity to get the artifacts published into it's NuGet feed. If your octo command tries to create a release using package versions that are not yet published the command (and build step) will fail. I build in a 30 second "sleep" in my script before running the octo.exe command to ensure that the build server has had time to publish the current version of the packages.